# Mysql query to get single user data from users table and its all addresses from addresses table

Tags: php, mysql

I have users table and addresses table.

I need to write a mysql query like:

```
SELECT * FROM users 
LEFT JOIN addresses 
   ON users.user_id = addresses.user_id 
WHERE users.user_id = 32;
```

This user has multiple addresses and I want to loop through its addresses in php while looping through users data like below:

```
foreach($users as $user){
    echo $user['username'];
    foreach($user['address'] as $address){
      echo $address['street_address'];
    }
}
```

Please help me writing the correct mysql query,Thanks.

Comment: what's problem?....share Db structure

Comment: Are the addresses comma-separated or on different rows

Comment: Unless you are doing some unnecessary concatenation with your results, you will have to iterate each row in a loop.  You will need to write a condition statement in the loop to echo the username on only the first iteration.  Each row's address will need to be echoed.

Answer (score 0):

> Considering addresses as separate table.

As you need all rows from addresses table, then why not to use `from addresses` like this:

```
select users.username,addresses.address from addresses as a right join users as u on u.user_id = a.user_id where u.user_id = 32;
```

Comment: Considering only two columns are necessary in the result set, drop the greedy asterisks.  `users.username` and `addresses.address`.  And as a matter of style, capitalize keywords for easy reading.  And if you are going to bother creating table aliases, use them in the select statement.

Comment: Depends upon requirement. He might need extra columns. Well i updated my answer according to your wil :)

Comment: If there is greater requirement, it is not mentioned in the question.

Comment: Not getting required result, it returning 2 result when a user has 2 addresses, there should be 1 result because there is only 1 user with id 32 in users table, and with your query how do i loop inside loop for address?

Comment: What is your requirement? obviously you will get 2 results of addresses. You want one address per user???

Answer (score 0):

This query extracts all addresses from table_address where the link with table_user using userid and verified.

```
SELECT tables_address.address FROM tables_address
INNER JOIN tables_user on tables_user.userid = tables_address.userid
WHERE tables_address.userid = X
```

I suggest you format the result of the query using the JSON format
{"Data": [{"aaa", "bbbb"}, {"aaa", "bbbb"}, ....]} and then use the json functions for PHP to process the return data